# Linux eventfd's initial value and use in a pollable Lock

Tags: python, c, linux, locking, polling

### Question

[`eventfd()`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/eventfd) is a new system call available in Linux since 2.6.22. The call signature is

```
int eventfd(unsigned int initval, int flags);
```

I am making use of this call in constructing a <s>new light saber</s>[`Lock`](http://docs.python.org/py3k/library/threading.html#lock-objects) class that's usable in a polling loop.

The Python [`Lock`](http://docs.python.org/py3k/library/threading.html#lock-objects) object starts in an unblocked state. My use of eventfd requires then that the initial value be non-zero. If the value is internally a `uint64_t`,

> The  object  contains an
>          unsigned 64-bit integer (uint64_t) counter that is  maintained  by  the
>          kernel.

why is the initial value argument of type `unsigned int`?

### Overt Detail

If I use non-zero values as the *unlocked* state of the `Lock`, releases are done by writing. Multiple releases without intervening acquires, are erroneous and need to fail. This requires that writing should fail when the event object contains a non-zero value. In its default mode, the event object will add values posted to it up to `(uint64_t)0xfffffffffffffffe`, before blocking write calls. To detect this situation I will do a nonblocking write that pushes the value over this maximum triggering this circumstance:

> If the addition would cause the counter's
>                 value to exceed the maximum, then  the  write(2)  either  blocks
>                 until  a  read(2)  is performed on the file descriptor, or fails
>                 with the error EAGAIN if the file descriptor has been made  non‐
>                 blocking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you want to have the state of this beast to alternate between `0` and `UINT64_MAX-1`?

The type of the initial value is probably just there for historical reasons. Once that such an interface is used it sticks and it is difficult to change it afterwards.

If you need the value to be initially `UINT64_MAX-1` why not just call `eventfd` with a `0` argument and do a `write` with `UINT64_MAX-1` immediately after, before you propagate the file descriptor to anybody else:

```
int ev = eventfd(0, 0);
write(ev, &(uint64_t const){ UINT64_MAX-1 }, sizeof(uint64_t));
```

(well you'll add the error checking code, don't you)

Comment: Wooh. Love the C99 there :P, nice touch.

Comment: well, radical as I am, I would even dare to put this inside a macro :) but I wouldn't show you how to do this in an answer because then people would downvote ;-)